Add-PnpGroupMember not working for app registration when adding external users
I am trying to automate the sharing of my site with external user and the PnP command let seems to not work.
When the command is run in the context of a user(Connect-PnPOnline -Interactive), it is doing what is supposed to.
But when I try to use it in the context of an app registration(Connect-PnpOnline -ClientId -ClientSecret) it is not throwing any error but it is not adding the user to the group.
Any suggestion would be greatly appreciated.

I have used fiddler and there is actually an error message, but I don't know how to fix it:
ErrorMessage=Please configure B2B collaboration settings correctly and troubleshoot first, "https://aka.ms/b2b-troubleshoot". Error from Entra B2B: No inviterEmail for invitation
